# What's the difference between [@] and [*] as array index?

Tags: arrays, shell

As stated in the [LDP: Bash-Beginners-Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html), using **[*]** and **[@]** both references all members of an array.

> 10.2.2. Dereferencing the variables in an array
>
> In order to refer to the content of an item in an array, use curly braces. This is necessary, as you can see from the following example, to bypass the shell interpretation of expansion operators. If the index number is @ or *, all members of an array are referenced.

```
array=(1 2 3)
echo ${array[*]}
# 1 2 3
echo ${array[@]}
# 1 2 3
```

I'm wondering what's the difference between them and what's the preferable form in terms of portability between shells (Korn, Dash, Bash, Zsh).

Comment: That guide is very... not good. This is just one of those cases. The bash reference manual section on [Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) covers the distinction between the two. As does the bash-hackers wiki section on [arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays).

Comment: @EtanReisner, thank you for the useful resources.